# Datacard Printer, using PrintDocument Failed to read default page settings of the printer

Tags: c#, printdocument

While using PrintDocument in c# web service, I am trying to read the printer default settings but always not success
example code :

The default PageSettings.Landscape is set to true from "Printers in control Panel"

```
        public string print_card(string strServer, string strPort, string strFileName, string strFileNameBack, int iDoubleFace)
        {
            string iResult = "";
            try
            {
                PrinterSettings mySet = new PrinterSettings();  
                strFileToPrint_Front = "http://" + strServer + ":" + strPort + "/" + strFileName;
                strFileToPrint_Back = "http://" + strServer + ":" + strPort + "/" + strFileNameBack;
                iPrintIndex = 0;
                _iDoubleFace = iDoubleFace;
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        //pd.PrinterSettings = mySet;
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings = mySet;
                //pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize= new PaperSize("card",  1063, 650);
                //pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape= true;
            //pd.PrinterSettings.Duplex = System.Drawing.Printing.Duplex.Horizontal;
                pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
                pd.Print();
                iResult = mySet.PrinterName;
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                iResult = ex.Message;
            }

            return iResult + strResult;
        }



        private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            string strToPrint;
            if (iPrintIndex == 0)
                strToPrint = strFileToPrint_Front;
            else
                strToPrint = strFileToPrint_Back;

            byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(strToPrint);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

        Rectangle m = e.PageBounds;
        if ((double) img.Width / (double) img.Height > (double) img.Width / (double) img.Height)
        {
           m.Height = (int) ((double) img.Height / (double) img.Width * (double) m.Width);
        } else 
        {
        m.Width = (int) ((double) img.Width / (double) img.Height * (double) m.Height); 
        }
            var size = img.Size;
            var width = size.Width;   

            //System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("http://localhost:8022/medical_card/311/medimgs/cards/card_8_246.jpg");
            Point loc = new Point(0, 0);
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 1063, 635);
            strResult = strResult + "," + width.ToString(); 
            if (_iDoubleFace == 2)
            {
                if (iPrintIndex == 0)
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                else
                    e.HasMorePages = false;



                iPrintIndex++;
            }



        }
```

However, it always return false when I call PrinterSettings();

I need this to use other special features in the printer, not the regular known features that I can set as I did below, like (impress card feature).

P.S. when I tried to make a console application using Delphi TPrinter, it did work
So, I tried to to call the EXE from the webService - it failed !!

Comment: What failure did you get using TPrinter?  I trying to find the source code for TPrinter and was not able to locate.  Probably the Trpinter is not using the standard method for reading page settings.  Try the escape characters from following manual : https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf  Do make sure you are doing it right I would start by sending the escape sequence to do a page feed.